# Can we use dataframe to join directly with teradata sql query , in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sas

In SAS , we can join directly the sas dataset with teradata table , but how can we achieve this in python using pandas.I know one option is , we can make two dataframe , one for sas dataset and other for teradata table ,and join them , but I guess, here it will take more to execute ,as join is excuted after two dataframes got created . can anyone know better option for this?

Comment: When you did it with SAS that was what has happening anyways, it just happened behind the scenes without you knowing it was happening.

Comment: I worked on SAS, it works like that on front, SAS provides the flexibiltiy to join dataset with teradata table in  sql query . finding the better and efficient way to achieve like this in python. one way, I know as mentioned in post

Comment: It allowed you to do that, but in the back end it was downloading both data sets and processing it locally, so your 'other way' was really the way SAS was doing it. Are you using the teradata package to connect? Depending on your join  maybe you can dynamically generate the code the way you would for an explicit SQL pass through query in SAS.

Comment: @Reeza,  Thanks, yes , I am using teradatasql package to connect. if SAS downloads the teradata table query dataset locally , then joins with other local dataset, so in this case forming two dataframe and joining them later should also take same execution time as SAS takes.

Comment: Assuming the same network speeds maybe, the tools can easily transfer data at different speeds so I wouldn't assume that's true. I would definitely look for a more dynamic option though, like I mentioned earlier you can create dynamic SQL in SAS to do a join, so maybe there's a way to do that in python as well.

Comment: @Reeza, yes I am looking for the way to do the mentioned in post in post in effiecient way